# Image not visible after include in html

Tags: html, path

I have an image in my theme folder in `img` directory and when I include my img in the `index.php` file, the image will be not shown. I'm using WordPress and want to know how I can show this image.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="header-img">
        <img src="imgbanner-image-1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

[i have img in img folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTESo.png)

Comment: Checking WordPress' [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) before asking questions here might be a good idea: [Linking Theme Files & Directories](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/linking-theme-files-directories/).

Comment: first line in wordpress.org 
1
echo get_theme_file_uri( 'images/logo.png' );
thank you <3

Comment: How should this work, is the index.php in the same directory as the image? You `src` is without a path. You should add a slash `/` after the `img`string and it should work, like `<img src="./img/banner-image-1.png"`

Comment: your code is wrong because i'm using localhost

Comment: when i write your code console show
     GET http://localhost/wordpress/img/banner-image-1.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: localhost is not a topic in this context, the path is important to the image. See also in the console of your browser and you should see the error.

Comment: The path on your comment is also wrong! WordPress leave the theme in  your context in `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-directory/img-directory/image.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using localhost and wanna include img use

```
src=" <?php echo get_theme_file_path('folder/img.png'); ?>"
```

Comment: That's not a point of localhost. The function give you the full url to the theme directory that is active in the installation.